# Getting 403 after logging in to GeoServer through keycloak

Tags: geoserver

I have been following [this guide](https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/community/keycloak/index.html) to secure my GeoServer with keycloak. After completing that tutorial I am still getting a 403 error after I login. I took care to follow the instructions at the bottom of the page that specifically mentions a 403 error.

Here are my configurations (with some sensitive information censored):

My keycloak is hosted at `auth.testing.xxx.xxx/auth`

Keycloak user `mntest` and the role mappings:
[image]

Keycloak geoserver-client config:
[image: keycloak geoserver-client config]

Keycloak fine grain details:
[image: keycloak fine grain details]

Geoserver keycloak_adapter config:
[image: Geoserver keycloak_adapter config]

Geoserver user:
[image: Geoserver user]

Geoserver web filter chain:
[image]

When I go to my GeoServer URL (geoservermn.testing.xxx.xxx) I get the login page:
[image: keycloak login]

After I login I expect to be redirected the GeoServer home. Instead, I get this 403:
[image: after login]

Does anyone know why I still get a 403? And what do I need to do to be redirected as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review the problem is solved by defining the location of your truststore in the geoserver 'keycloak_adapter' config like so:

`"truststore": "/usr/local/tomcat/my-keystore.jks",
 "truststore-password": "changeit",`

The truststore can be generated from a cert like so:
`keytool -import -alias mytruststore -trustcacerts -file <path_to_cert.cer> -keystore <new_jks_filename.jks>`

Comment: Have you tried removing the secret key parameter from the json? I guess yours is working just because secret is in the template. It might not work only with the realm-public-key

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when authenticating over SSL. I was using reverse proxy (SSL termination point) in front of GeoServer running on Tomcat. GeoServer's log showed this error:

```
ERROR [adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] - Adapter requires SSL. Request: http://mydomain/geoserver/ows?...
```

URL in the log was `http://...` despite my browser showing me `https://...`.

The solution that worked for me was:

- On reverse proxy, add the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header to requests going to GeoServer.
- On Tomcat, add the `RemoteIpValve` with attribute `protocolHeader` to the `server.xml` file, like this:

```xml
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        ...
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
      </Host>
...
```

You can look [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve) for docs on Tomcat's Remote IP Valve.